# scala implicit class method type mismatch in reduce vs non-implicit method with function currying

Tags: function, scala, currying, implicits

## Problem:

Something about implicit class, confuses reduce().
When inside implicit class, compiler complains on reduce() second parameter.
but when same code is inside non-implicit method it compiles and works fine.

What am I missing about implicit classes?

### Code:

```
object ImpliCurri {
    implicit class MySeq[Int](val l: Seq[Int]) {
        //not compiling
        final def mapSum(f:Int=>Int):Int = {
            l.map(x=>f(x)).reduce(_+_)
       //compile error on reduce: Type mismatch. Expected String, fount Int
        }
    }

    // works fine
    def mySum(l:Seq[Int], f:Int=>Int):Int = {
        l.map(x=>f(x)).reduce(_+_)
        // compiles and works no issues
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't actually have anything to do with implicits.  You get the same error if it's just a regular `class`.

The reason is that you have declared a generic type: `MySeq[Int]` that just happens to be called `Int`.  So when you say `f: Int => Int` you think "Oh, that's an integer" and the compiler thinks, "Oh, that means you could fill in any type there!".  (Replace all your `Int`s with `A` and it would work the same.)

Now the compiler is in a bind.  What `+` can you apply to any pair of types?  Well, you can convert anything to a `String`, and `+` is defined on a `String`.  So you get a very misleading error message when the compiler realizes that this approach won't work.

Just drop the `[Int]` and all your `Int`s will actually mean what you think they mean, and the implicit class version will work fine.

Answer (score 5):

You need to get rid of the type parameter `Int`. `Int` in the case of the implicit class is not actually the type `Int`, but instead it's a free type parameter that's shadowing the name of `Int`.

The reason for the cryptic compiler error is that the compiler is inferring the type `Any` from the lambda `_ + _` (since the type parameter could be anything), and assuming the `+` will come from a `toString` on type `Any`. If you replace `Int` with `T` in the class declaration, you'll see the error is the same.

This will work:

```
implicit class MySeq(val l: Seq[Int]) {
    final def mapSum(f: Int => Int): Int = {
        l.map(x => f(x)).reduce(_ + _)
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `MySeq[Int](val l: Seq[Int])` with `MySeq(val l: Seq[Int])`.

Explanation of the compiler message:
The `MySeq[Int]` part defines an abstract type parameter for class `MySeq` named `Int`, which is (automatically) a subclass of `Any` and shadows the actual `scala.Int`. Then the compiler tries to call `+` method of an instance of `Any`. It sees a declaration of an implicit class `scala.Predef.any2stringadd`, which has a method with signature `def +(other: String): String`, so the compiler thinks the second parameter to `+` should be a `String`.